# How do you debug react-native in Ubuntu 14.10?

Tags: debugging, browser, react-native

How does one debug their react code with react-native while the app is running in android device?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Run this command to open developer menu - `adb shell input keyevent 82`
2. Select "Debug in chrome"
3. A new tab in chrome will be opened.
4. Right click, select *Inspect Elements*
5. Select *Console* tab.
6. Done

If you want to print error messages from your app, write `console.log("error string or anything")`. You can also display in-app warnings by using `console.warn("error string")`

Hope this helps. Also, please read the documentation first before you post a question. [Document for debugging](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/debugging.html). Good luck!

Comment: @Devux awesome. Please accept my answer, if you will :)

Comment: @Devux Thank you! Anytime!